# Bios failed to detect USB Drive

Tags: boot, usb, bios

This is my Problem:

Before my BIOS Update I can boot directly from my Pen drive by pressing F9 key to install Ubuntu.

Now I cannot able to boot from my pendrive.
I have enabled Legacy Support and disabled Secure Boot.
But Boot Manager does not show any USB Drive Entry to boot.

I have tried the following:

- Bios Restored to Old version.
- Created Bootable Live USB using
  Universal USB Installer.

About Laptop:
My Laptop Model is HP Pavilion 15 -e039tx
BIOS Version :Insyde F 23

Hiw do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is placing the USB drive onto a different port, perhaps using a USB 2.0 if you aren't already.

Additionally, you could try accessing your BIOS and then directly booting from the USB there, instead of using F9.

Hope it helps!